# CASE statements in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, case, hiveql

Ok, i have a following code to mark records that have highest month_cd in tabl with binary flag:

```
Select t1.month_cd, t2.max_month_cd
  ,CASE WHEN t2.max_month_cd != null then 0 else 1 end test_1
  ,CASE WHEN t2.max_month_cd = null then 0 else 1 end test_2
from source t1
Left join (
  Select 
    MAX(month_cd) as max_month_cd 
  From source 
) t2 
on t1.month_cd = t2.max_month_cd;
```

It seems straight forward to me, but result it return is:

```
month_cd  max_month_cd  test_1  test_2
201610    null          1       1
201611    201611        1       1
```

Makes zero sense to me, and seems to be way too obvious to be a bug in execution engine. What am i missing?

Answer (score 21):

This is all about NULL concept.

Since Null is not a member of any data domain, it is not considered a "value", but rather a marker indicating the absence of value. Because of this, comparisons with Null can never result in either True or False, but always in a third logical result, Unknown. NULL is nothing, absence of object. So, nothing can NOT be equal to NULL or something else. In SQL there are `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` conditions to be used for test for null values.

In your CASE the result of logical expression is unknown, so ELSE value is assigned.

Corrected version:

```
CASE WHEN t2.max_month_cd IS NOT null then 0 else 1 end test_1,
CASE WHEN t2.max_month_cd IS null     then 0 else 1 end test_2
```

See this for reference: [Null (SQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Comparisons_with_NULL_and_the_three-valued_logic_.283VL.29)